# Uncaught Error: document.myForm.submit(); is not a function - After 2nd call

Tags: javascript, html

The autosubmit `document.myForm.submit();` works fine if I call it once, but I'm trying to call it multiple times and after 1st attempt, the other times give out an error `Uncaught Error: document.myForm.submit();` the code works 100% fine UNTIL I call more than once. Is this normal? How do I avoid it?

Research shows that most likely my form inputs are named Submit, which is not the case

I'm using Phonegap/Cordova:

```
function sendData()//Gets called once per second
{
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",

    '<form name=\"myForm\" action=\"http://www.mywebsite.com/formProcess.php\" method=\"POST\" target=\"submission.frame\">' +
    '<input type=\"text\"   name = "uuid" value=\"' + String(uuid)  + '\">' +
    '<input type=\"text\"   name = "directionX" value=\"' + String(directionX)  + '\">' +
    '<input type=\"text\"   name = "directionY" value=\"' + String(directionY)  + '\">' +
    '<iframe name=\"submission.frame\" hidden></iframe>'                                +
    '</form>'

    );

    document.myForm.submit();
}
```

Server PHP

```
<?php
//Do bunch of stuff
?>
<form name="myForm" action="<?php echo $current_file; ?>" method="POST">
UUID       <input type="text" name="uuid">      <br>
directionX <input type="text" name="directionX"><br>
directionY <input type="text" name="directionY"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: How exactly you call `document.myForm.submit()` the second time?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: post a verifiable snippet of code that highlights the problem.

Comment: Could you give us the code?

Comment: I didn't see your code, but I think there was an error when first submitting. That can be looks like working first time, but after, it won't work anymore before refresh the page.

Comment: I added my javascript code

Comment: Also added php snippet

Comment: @modernator It seems likely.. but how would I refresh the page? I have tried `document.myForm.reset();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you call it, you add a form to the document and then `document.myForm` is that form element.

The second time you call it, you add *another* form  (with the *same name*!) to the document and then `document.myForm` is an HTML Element Collection (which is an array-like object) containing **two** forms.

The collection doesn't have a `submit` method. The two elements inside it do.

You could compensate for that by testing to see if there is a submit method and then grabbing the last element in the collection if it fails…

```
if (document.myForm.submit) {
    document.myForm.submit();
} else {
    document.myForm[document.myForm.length - 1].submit();
}
```

… but it really looks like you would be better off just switching to [use XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) instead of throwing forms and iframes into the document. Those are what we used before Microsoft came up with XMLHttpRequest in the late 90s for the Outlook web app.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. I didn't think I'd need to upload code so sorry for vague question.

I just started learning php/mysql, I realize the forms are a sloppy way but gives a visual learning :)
One question though please: is XMLHttpRequest a lot faster than submitting a form? If I try submitting form 20 per sec it crashes, but 1 per second is ok. Would I be able to do that fast with it? --Basically the code all does is submit X and Y coordinates of a game.

Comment: It isn't a lot faster. It is more robust though. You might want to investigate WebSockets.

Comment: Thank you very much